# Rails 3.2 Ajax Update Div when Text Field Populated Many to Many Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.1

In the end I would like a text field that passes a client_id to the partial.  I would like to do this asynchronously so the shipment_products partial would dynamically change when the textfield value was updated. What is the best way to do this?

In index.html.erb

```
<!-- Text Field Here-->
<div id="available_products">
  <%= render "shipment_products" %>
</div>
```

In _shipment_products.html.erb

```
<div id="shipment_products_container">
  <h3>Assign Products to Ship<\h3>
  <ul class="shipment_products" id="shipment_products">
    <% Product.by_client(client_id).each do |product|%>  <!-- TextField value passed here -->
      <%= content_tag_for :li, product, :value => product.id do %>
        <%= hidden_field_tag("shipment[product_ids][]", product.id) %>
        <%= product.product_name %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <\ul>
</div>
```

Model relationships:

```
Models and Relationships
  Shipment  has_many :products :through => :shipment_products
  Product   has_many :shipments :through => :shipment_products
  ShipmentProducts belongs_to :shipment,  belongs_to :product
  Product belongs_to :client
  Client has_many :products
```

This is similar to what I want in the end. [image]

Answer (score 0):

Since I do not know what's in your controller and how you make routes, I made some suggestions. Change a few things to the actual. I assume that you do not need to change `index` action (if only to add `respond_to` js)

index.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag shipment_path, remote: true do %> - points to index action
  <%= text_field_tag :client_id %>
  <%= submit_tag :load %>
<% end %>
<div id="available_products">
  <%= render "shipment_products" %>
</div>
```

index.js.erb

```
$('#available_products').html("<%= j render "shipment_products" %>");
```

Comment: How do I pass the value of the client id text_field to the by_clients method in the partial?  And how would I do that on say a jQuery blur event?

Comment: 1. In your controller `index` action: `@client = Client.find(params[:client_id])`. Now, you can use in your partials `@client` E.g. `Product.by_client(@client.id)`. 2. `$('.my-super-form').submit();`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use nested model concept for this please refer-

http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2?view=asciicast

Comment: I finally figured it out.  Since the bounty is ending tomorrow I'll be a good citizen and award u the bounty. Give u a boost of rep.  Your answer is better than the other answer.